# rust-analyzer not working in NeoVim on Windows 10

Tags: neovim, lsp

I'm trying to get rust-analyzer working in Neovim, but with no luck so far.

I've downloaded the rust-analyzer binary (`rust-analyzer-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc.gz`) from the rust-analyzer releases page and put it in my PATH (specifically in `%USERPROFILE%\.rustup\toolchains\rust-analyzer-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`).

I have the language server enabled in my init.lua but when I open a source file in a rust project and enter `:LspInfo` I get the following:

```
 Config: rust_analyzer
    filetypes:         rust
    root directory:    C:\Users\[my user name]\source\repos\rust\loops
    cmd:               rust-analyzer
    cmd is executable: Unable to find executable. Please check your path and ensure the server is installed
    autostart:         true
    custom handlers:
```

My init.lua for lsp config looks like this:

```
local servers = { 'gopls', 'lemminx', 'rust_analyzer' }
for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
    nvim_lsp[lsp].setup {
        on_attach = on_attach,
        capabilities = capabilities,
    }
end
```

`gopls` is working all fine, so I think that config is correct. But rust-analyzer just doesn't seem to work.

I've also tried installing rust-analyzer in VSCode in case neovim can use that one, but that didn't appear to work either.

I'm using v0.5.0 of neovim.

I read on some webpage that I've now lost that the rust-analyzer MSVC needs to be registered but I can't find any info on how to register an MSVC.

For comparison, this is what `:LspInfo` shows when I have a Go source file open and the `gopls` LSP is attached:

```
 Client: gopls (id: 1, pid: 59572, bufnr: [1])
    filetypes:       go, gomod
    autostart:       true
    root directory:  C:\Users\[my user name]\source\repos\go\k6-extensions\xk6-wsrte
    cmd:             gopls
```

Comment: Can you run the command `rust-analyzer`, or is the command `rust-analyzer-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`? It's not clear from your description of the paths involved

Comment: @D.BenKnoble that's a very good question and I don't know the answer. What's baffling me is that the init.lua says `rust_analyzer` but the error message says `rust-analyzer`. I don't know where the `cmd` value is coming from. Running `rust-analyzer` or `rust_analyzer` from command line just gets the "is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet etc" response. Same for trying `rust-analyzer-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`.

Comment: Ah, I finally stumbled across what I was doing wrong! I'll self-answer.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I also discovered that in the `nvim-lspconfig` folders there's a `rust_analyzer.lua` file that defines the `cmd` - which is 'rust-analyzer'. This has been most educational!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had missed the section of the documentation that says:

> Other editors generally require the rust-analyzer binary to be in
> $PATH. You can download pre-built binaries from the releases page. You
> will need to uncompress and rename the binary for your platform, e.g.
> from rust-analyzer-aarch64-apple-darwin.gz on Mac OS to rust-analyzer,
> make it executable, then move it into a directory in your $PATH.

Once I have renamed the `rust-analyzer-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` file to `rust-analyzer.exe` when I opened a rust source file in nvim I got this from `:LspInfo`:

```
 Client: rust_analyzer (id: 1, pid: 57880, bufnr: [1])
    filetypes:       rust
    autostart:       true
    root directory:  C:\Users\[my user name]\source\repos\rust\loops
    cmd:             rust-analyzer
```